Prometheus/Grafana Query: Handling Empty Tag Values in Metric Visualization
I have a Prometheus metric with two tags: op and type, where type can have an empty value (""). In Grafana, I visualize this metric using two optional/multi-value variables, op and type.
The query I'm using is:
sum(rate(metric{op=~"$op", type=~"$type"}[1m:15s]))

Here's the issue:

When op = x, type has a value.
When op = y, type is empty.
When selecting op = x, type = All from Grafana variables, the result is correct.
When selecting op = y, type = All from Grafana variables, the result is correct.
However, when selecting both (op = x, y, type = All), the result is incorrect.
It seems that op = y is not being counted. Why is this happening?

Could someone please advise on how to correct this behavior?
op = x:

op = y:

op = x, y:


What is the value of $type in both cases?

The All  options is selected.

Go to inspect panel, and show us your query, after Grafana substituted variable. Probably something wrong with variable type there.
